# CSS - Push right to left menu in responsive state

Tags: jquery, css

See my works: http://codepen.io/leoaivy/pen/xZzKxm

When you click the menu button to open the menu and narrow the window, it looks very weird, especially on small widths. I know I can use media query but unfortunately, when you don't click the menu button and narrow the window, I also have to use media query for this situation.

This leads to two cases, when the menu button is clicked and not, which is rather confusing (I really don't want to use media queries for both two cases because of its complexity).

Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much!

Some codes related to the problem:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-push-right-to-left">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/common/icon-logo-quark-3.png" alt=""><span>@ 20xx Text.com, Inc.</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">- Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">- Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">- Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">- Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">- Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">- Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">- Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="block-social">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="qa qa-wifi"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="qa qa-social-facebook"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="qa qa-social-twitter"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="qa qa-social-linkedin"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="qa qa-social-google"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="block-contact">
        <h4><a href="#">Text</a>
        </h4>
        <p>
            Text
            <br> Text: xxxx-0000
            <br> Text: <a href="mailto:help@quark.band" title="help@quark.band">help@test.test</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.menu-push-right-to-left {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -324px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 324px;
    transition: right .3s ease-out, visibility .3s ease-out;
    background-color: $black-2;
    &.changeWidth {
        right: 0;
    }
    ul {
        float: none;
    }
    nav li {
        float: none;
        padding: px2em(22px) px2em(27px);
        border-bottom: 1px solid $gray-17;
        &:first-child {
            padding: px2em(13px) px2em(21px) px2em(12px);
            a {
                font-size: px2em(12px);
            }
            img {
                float: left;
            }
            span {
                float: left;
                color: white;
                line-height: inherit;
                margin: px2em(10px, 12px) 0 0 px2em(7px, 12px);
            }
        }
        a {
            color: white;
            padding: 0 0 0;
        }
    }

    ul.block-social {
        margin: px2em(29px) 0 0;
        li {
            float: none;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 0 0 px2em(40px);
            vertical-align: bottom;
            span {
                color: $white-4;
                &.qa-social-facebook {
                    font-size: px2em(21px, 15px);
                    line-height: px2em(20px, 21px);
                }
                &.qa-social-linkedin {
                    font-size: px2em(18px, 15px);
                }
                &.qa-social-google {
                    font-size: px2em(19px, 15px);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .block-contact {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0 px2em(32px) px2em(27px);
        h4 {
            font-size: inherit;
            line-height: inherit;
            a {
                color: white;
                font-size: px2em(12px);
                line-height: px2em(24px, 12px);
            }
        }
        p {
            color: $gray-9;
            font-size: px2em(12px);
            line-height: px2em(24px, 12px);
            a {
                color: $gray-9;
            }
        }
    }
}   // end .menu-push-right-to-left
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with this

```
@media your max width here {

   .menu-push-right-to-left {
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    width: auto;
    height:0
    transition: height .3s ease-out, visibility .3s ease-out;

        &.changeWidth {
            height:auto;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries really are the only answer to this. As for clicking then resizing that would need jquery to watch - and a bit tricky in Chrome to do this but I think you are over complicating it. 
No one really resizes the browser so no need for the watch. Just add one query in for smaller devices (of course you could add more, say orientations too.).

Hope this helps - just dont over think what users could do because invariably if they opened the menu then changed their screen and it looked odd they would revert their action in reality.